# SQL STATEMENT Values getting multiplied by 3

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

SUM(ISNULL(FlagHrs,0.00) + ISNULL(BackFlagSoldHrs,0.00)) AS Ttl_EmpFlagHrs

Using this statement in a select statement but the values I am getting in Ttl_EmpFlagHrs are getting multiplied by 3, Flaghrs and BackFlaghrs are the different columns present in a certain table.

Comment: can please you share the complete query and a sample data

Comment: Please share the details of the columns you are grouping by and whether you are using this in a join?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that there's a join involved, probably a one-to-many join, resulting in multiple lines being returned...

Comment: What is the question? How to get the correct result? Divide by three might be an option ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no sample data or full query, you are forcing us to answer based on speculation.

Based on your question, Objective is to add `FlagHrs` and `BackFlagSoldHrs` and when its null, count it as zero.

Since you are using `SUM` function, which is a group function, result of multiple rows will be added and presented as a single value.

Based on your question, it is highly likely that, single row is repeated 3 times (could be result of a join) and hence sum is showing up as 3 times.

You can verify this by removing `SUM` function and checking rows actually selected as result of your query.

**Solution**:

1. Verify Join condition to ensure correct rows are selected in your query
2. If theory of adding it up multiple times is true, you can use `AVG` function in place of `SUM` function, the result will be equivalent of single row (rather than 3x)
3. See if you need to use `DISTINCT` keyword to remove duplicate rows (if its not desired result)